# Get typeof of the value in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using ES6 + babel with a plugin of ["iife-wrap"].

I am trying to remake the plugin I create before (form-validation). I am trying to check if the data is an object.

For es5 this is just: `typeof blah === 'object'` or `string, function, and etc.`

However if I put it on es6. It will produce an error of **Uncaught TypeError: _typeof is not a function**

Here's a sample piece of my code.

```
let es6function = () => {
    return 'asd';
}

console.log(typeof es6function)

class Person {

}

let tryThis = new Person()
console.log(tryThis instanceof Person)
```

ES5: Post-compiled

```
;

(function () {
    'use strict';

    function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
        if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
            throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
        }
    }

    var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && _typeof(Symbol.iterator) === "symbol" ? function (obj) {
        return typeof obj === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(obj);
    } : function (obj) {
        return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(obj);
    };

    var es6function = function es6function() {
        return 'asd';
    };

    console.log(typeof es6function === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(es6function));

    var Person = function Person() {
        _classCallCheck(this, Person);
    };

    var tryThis = new Person();
    console.log(tryThis instanceof Person);
})();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is almost definitely something to do with your transpiler (babel). It works as expected in a browser that supports ES6 natively.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, the error says `_typeof`, are you sure you don't have a typo

Comment: I mean the transpiled one. Wait, I'll edit.

Comment: Works fine [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20es6function%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(typeof%20es6function)%0A%0Aclass%20Person%20%7B%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20tryThis%20%3D%20new%20Person()%0Aconsole.log(tryThis%20instanceof%20Person)).

Comment: @FelixKling Try to run it through browser. You'll see the error in console.

Comment: You mean the compiled code? Works fine in the console as well. The output is `function` and `true`.

Comment: I guess you didn't copy and post the whole code. Proof that it works: http://imgur.com/a/8XqZA . Even if you look at the code `_typeof` is always assigned a function value.

Comment: I forgot to include the plugin I used. Sorry. It will work but if I put IIFE-wrap. This won't work. My bad.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Which Babel version? What you posted is not what Babel generates by default. We can't help you if you don't provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124689/discussion-between-user111111-and-felix-kling).

Comment: Well, you can see that invalid output is produced: `var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && _typeof(Symbol.iterator) === "symbol" `. The `_typeof` call shouldn't be there. Now, why this happens only when you include the plugin I can't say. Could be a bug in Babel. It certainly doesn't have anything to do with ES6 itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are accidentally running Babel in two passes over your code.

The ES6 code

```
console.log(typeof es6function)
```

does get transpiled to

```
var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol" ? function (obj) { return typeof obj; } : function (obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol ? "symbol" : typeof obj; };

console.log(typeof es6function === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(es6function));
```

which does become

```
var _typeof2 = typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol" ? function (obj) { return typeof obj; } : function (obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol ? "symbol" : typeof obj; };

var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && _typeof2(Symbol.iterator) === "symbol" ? function (obj) {
    return typeof obj === "undefined" ? "undefined" : _typeof2(obj);
} : function (obj) {
    return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol ? "symbol" : typeof obj === "undefined" ? "undefined" : _typeof2(obj);
};

console.log(typeof es6function === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(es6function));
```

when you transpile it again. Apart from the `_typeof`/`_typeof2` duplication this does look a lot like your transpilation result. Check your build configuration and babel plugins. Try to disable one after the other to see when the problem will go away, and report a bug with the responsible component.

Answer (score -3):

Can you add parentheses to wrap like this?

```
if( typeof(Symbol) === 'function') ) { ... }
```

Comment: And why should the OP do that? `typeof` is an operator. The parenthesis are useless. `typeof foo` is the same as `typeof (foo)` is the same as `typeof ((((((foo))))))`.

Comment: Indeed both ways should work, but I think that the cause may be the compiler

Comment: Your proposal is syntactically invalid.